# How to access form body in oak/deno

Tags: deno, oak

I'm using oak/deno. I have a form that is submitted from an ejs file served up. How do I access the form body? When I log it to the console, it prints: `{type: "form", value: URLSearchParamsImpl {} }`

The post handler is shown below:

```js
router.post("/add", async (ctx: RouterContext) => {
  const body = (await ctx.request.body())
  console.log(body)
  ctx.response.redirect("/");
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` just use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instance available in `body.value`.

```js
body.value.get('yourFieldName')
```

If `body.type === "form-data"` you can use `.value.read()` and you'll get the `multipart/form-data` fields

```js
router.post("/add", async (ctx: RouterContext) => {
  const body = await ctx.request.body({ type: 'form-data '});
  const formData = await body.value.read();
  console.log(formData.fields);
  ctx.response.redirect("/");
});
```

Comment: This works correctly and allows access to the form data however the example mentions `multipart/form` data. How can the files be accessed?

Answer (score 4):

something like this returns the values

it looked like `body.value` is accessed through `.get(<key>)` or can be iterated with `.entries()` or `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
async register(context: RouterContext) {
  const body = context.request.body({ type: 'form' })
  const value = await body.value

  console.log(value.get('email'))

  for (const [key, val] of value.entries()) {
    console.log(key, val)
  }

  const args = Object.fromEntries(value)
  console.log(args)

  context.response.body = 'test'
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include  an explanation of how this works and why it is of solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Comment: Thanks, that worked out fine! I'm using json body, so my code was a bit different:

```const body = ctx.request.body({ type: 'json' }); const parsedBody = await body.value;
```