# Handling multipart/form-data with Deno and Oak

Tags: javascript, forms, upload, deno, oak

I'm making slow but steady progress in learning Deno and Oak but this has me stumped. I have a simple web form with a file upload field:

```html
<form method="post" action="/quote" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Author:
  <input type="text" name="author" />
  </label>
  <label>file: <input type="file" name="myfile" multiple />
  </label>
  <label>Quote: 
  <textarea name="quote"></textarea>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

The processing is done with Deno and Oak and here is the script that handles the text data:

```js
router.post('/quote', async context => {
const body = context.request.body({ type: 'form' })
  const value = await body.value
  const author = value.get('author')
  console.log(author)
  context.response.redirect(`/?author=${author}`)
})
```

The route can handle a form which does **not** have an encoding of `multipart/form-data` but as soon as I add that, the `author` field is `undefined`.

My question is: how can I access the data from this form (both the text and file data)?

Comment: Is there any way to handle file uploads in Oak? I've seen a couple of tutorials but they all use broken libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is buried in the [Oak documentation](https://github.com/kitsonk/oak). The `Request` property of the `Context` object includes a `body()` method. This "resolves to a version of the request body".

It takes an `options` object that implements the `BodyOptions` interface. It has a single property called `type` which needs to have a value of `form-data` if you intend parsing `multipart/form-data`.

In this scenario it returns an object that implements the `FormDataReader` interface and this includes a `read()` method that resolves to an object containing the data from *all the form fields*, including any files uploaded.

Here is an example of how it should be implemented:

```js
router.post('/foo', async context => {
    const body = await context.request.body({ type: 'form-data'})
    const data = await body.value.read()
    console.log(data)
    context.response.redirect('/')
})
```

And here is an example of the output. It includes a `fields` property which contains the data from the form fields and a `files` array which contains the data for all the files you uploaded:

```json
{
  fields: { name: "Foo", organisation: "Bar" },
  files: [
    {
      content: undefined,
      contentType: "image/png",
      name: "myimage",
      filename: "/tmp/c8290ba0/e25ee9648e3e5db57f5ef3eb4cfa06704ce5f29c.png",
      originalName: "foobar.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why is content undefined? Shouldn't the image data be there?

Comment: @chovy I was also getting 'undefined', fixed it by adding a maxSize parameter to read, like so:
const data = await body.value.read({ maxSize: 10_000_000 })

Answer (score -2):

```
router.post('/quote', async context => {        
    let params: {[key: string]: string} = {};
    let value: any = await context.request.body().value;
    for (const [key, valor] of value) {
        params[key] = valor; 
    }
    const author = params['author']
    console.log(author)
    context.response.redirect(`/?author=${author}`)
})
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and don't just post code. It helps the person who posted the question to learn from it instead of reinforcing copy-paste coding

Comment: Sorry, there are many ways to access the data from a form, maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363699/how-to-access-form-body-in-oak-deno shows a more detailed answer